# Neural Network For Threat Analysis

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

For a game that I am developing, I have decided to use a Neural Network for character threat analysis. When a character spots another character in the game, they will use a neural network to determine whether or not to engage that character. It is a 3 layer feed forward network.

Inputs:

- Health Difference (myHP - enemyHP)
- Level difference
- Ally vs enemy count (numAllies - numEnemies)
- A boolean variable that indicates the presence of a very strong enemy

My main question is with regards to the input and activation function. I have implemented the network to use a logistic function. How best could I normalize my inputs to fit the function?

For example health difference may range from 1% to 100% where as level difference could be from -40 to +40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift and scale your inputs so all of them are in `<0; 1>`.

If your input `x` is in `<a; b>` and you want it to be in `<0; 1>`, do this:

1. Subtract `a`, so we have `x - a`. `x` now is non-negative.
2. Divide by `b - a`, so we have `(x - a) / (b - a)`. `x` now is in <0; 1>.

Example. Let `x` = your level difference input. It's in <-40; 40> initially.

1. Subtract -40, we land in <0; 80>.
2. Divide by 80, we land in <0; 1>.

Answer (score 0):

Why not translating all your values to the [0;1] interval ?
For instance to find the health normalization function, you're looking for `a` and `b` such as

```
a * 0.01 + b = 0
a * 1 + b= 1
```

Giving : `a=1/0.99 and b=-0.01/0.99`

Same for level difference : you're looking for `c` and `d` such as :

```
c * (-40) + d = 0
c * 40 + d = 1
```

And so on...

For each variable your translation function will be of the form `a*x+b` where `a` and `b` are found as above.